# Java String split Questions

Tags: java, string, split

I was wondering why the result of splitting the string

> foo:and:boo

with regex

> o

has an empty space in it?
so the output looks like this -

> f "" and b

Can someone explain why "" is here? thanks!

Comment: Because between the `oo` there is no character.

Answer (score 5):

> Can someone explain why "" is here?

Because there's nothing between the `o` and `o` in `foo`. The regex `o` splits on each and every individual `o` in the string.

If you used `o+`, then you wouldn't have the `""` because you're saying "split on one **or more** `o`s":

[**Live Example**](http://ideone.com/KckDR0)

```
class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "foo:and:boo";
        test("Results from using just \"o\":", str, "o");
        test("Results from using \"o+\":",     str, "o+");
    }

    private static void test(String label, String str, String rex)
    {
        String[] results = str.split(rex);
        System.out.println(label);
        for (String result : results) {
            System.out.println("[" + result + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Results from using just "o":
[f]
[]
[:and:b]
Results from using "o+":
[f]
[:and:b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on "o" will split on each "o" found:

> "ok".split("o");

Give the result :

1. "" ->index 0 (included) to index 1 (not included)
2. k  -> index 1 (included) to index 2 (not included)

Because index 0 match your regex "o". But why foo doesn't return "" too ?

The documentation of split says:

> *Trailing* empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting
>   array.

The trailling means at the end of the regex. If you add something after "boo" :
    String source = "foo:and:boot";
    String[] os = source.split("o");

```
System.out.println(String.format("Size of result is [%s]", os.length));
for (int i = 0; i < os.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + os[i]);
}
```

The output will be :

```
Size of result is [5]
0 f
1 
2 :and:b
3 
4 t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can understand this well if you know how index in regex works.

Below image is copied from  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html).

[image]

As you can see, though "foo" length is only 3 characters, start index is 0 and **end index** is 3.

Now, if you say split on "o" (only one occurence of o), you can see that there is nothng betwen cell1(o) and cell2(o), so it gives empty string. As others  mentioned, if you use "o+" (one or more occurences of the letter o) for splitting, you won't get the empty string. Hope I'm clear.